# A Small GUI Linux System with UEFI completely running on RAMDisk

Tags: arch-linux, uefi, gui, initrd, mkinitcpio

I am developing a POS System and I am planning to use Linux.
My requirements are as follows

1. UEFI Support. (Running on x86 and x86_64)
2. No Storage Drive so completely running on RAM and persistence storage data(Around 1 MB) will be in ESP (EFI System Partition)
3. A GUI Application displaying options for POS.
4. Wireless connectivity (Not immediately but eventually)
5. No installation required. (Just copy kernel and initrd images to ESP along with systemd-boot and good to go.)

I have been able to run Minimal Live Linux (https://github.com/ivandavidov/minimal) where kernel and initrd images are stored in EFI System Partition. It could connect to Wired Network and I could login to Bash.

Next step is to load GUI (XOrg or Something else) and add my own GUI application.

I am stuck at a point where I want to create a initrd image with GUI support.

Any pointers on that direction?

Comment: Try to narrow your question down to a single problem. You say: _I am stuck at a point where I want to create a initrd image with GUI support._ Well, that is exactly the kind of thing people here might be able to help you with. But you need to explain what the actual problem is.

Comment: Something like these? Lightweight Desktop environment
Ubuntu Server + lxde or openbox or fluxbox, but without all the applications included in a full desktop distribution. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerGUI Default minimal does not support UEFI, but can be reconfigured. Usually server install is used without any server applications. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2419997&p=13862419#post13862419

Comment: @oldfred, Thanks. I will try mini and update.

Comment: I could create a small footprint linux using Buildroot with X11 enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You might prefer learning to create custom LiveCDs, the description reads quite like that; for one, I'd go with mkimage-profiles (disclaimer: I've designed it back in 2010), that would only take me to package the target app and configure [livecd-runapp](http://packages.altlinux.org/en/sisyphus/srpms/livecd-runapp) package to autorun it; the rest seems done by generating a hybrid ISO that can be installed by just dd'ing it on an USB Flash, SSD, DoM or whatever comes around.  You can try this approach through [ALT Starterkits](http://en.altlinux.org/starterkits); with it, you'll also be able to quickly adapt for e.g. RPi as the POS platform.

But [mkimage-profiles](http://ru.altlinux.org/m-p) is mostly documented in Russian albeit a few guys found it good enough through google translate and example requests.

The easiest way might be to go with SUSE's [OBS](http://build.opensuse.org/), you'll still need to build the app package though.